# Do qualia have an evolutionary purpose? (assuming they exist)

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, computation, qualia, evolution

Do qualia have an evolutionary function, and if so what is it?

Could qualia help us solve problems that Turing machines can't solve?

Could qualia help us solve problems faster than normal computers?

Our brain often works like a general problem solving machine. Could qualia have evolved to optimize this machine? Could evolution limit it to solving only the problems that our genes are "interested" in? Could qualia have other purposes?

Comment: What makes you think C-T is true? And what makes you think that computing functions on the natural numbers is something done by the brain? And if you don't believe in qualia ... are you saying you have none? It's a question only a zombie could ask. Clarify please?

Comment: I do believe in qualia personally. If qualia do give us super computing powers what impact might that have on CT and completely theory?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that only things that give us computing powers have a purpose?

Comment: Well, computing power is one possible purpose of qualia. Im interested in the implications of that purpose and any other purpose qualia might have. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Sure, I think it's a good question about qualia and its purposes, but I'm just not sure the computing part makes your question clearer. If it's not central to your question I'd consider removing it and asking the question more generally.

Comment: The purpose of sense images and the subjective feelings associated with them under a more classic account is the transmission of objective reality to a person. Under a post-Cartesian analysis, 'qualia' exist as a way to uphold a contingent realism (a realism in which we have 'indirect' access to reality). So the purpose of qualia in the tradition of indirect realism is largely to uphold a weaker form of realism in light of the possibility that the mind can supposedly be misled as to what is actually out there in the sensory world. Qualia don't really have practical bearings, so far as I see it

Comment: What do you mean by "I do believe in qualia personally". You did not define qualia. For example, most people (e.g. on this website) may use the term qualia to refer to a thing in their mind, and yet they may insist that they see nothing in their mind that cannot be expressed as (Turing) computation.

Comment: As I read it, you have about 8 questions, and 0 definitions on what you understand as qualia.  This makes it almost impossible to answer your question!

Comment: The question is surreal. I can make no sense of it. Is the questionner a zombie?

Answer (score 3):

Qualia are supposed to be (by definition) not the causes of any physical events, hence there is no way that they could enter into evolutionary or any other kinds of scientific explanation of a phenomenon. For instance, imagine there were ghosts which simply couldn't cause any events in the physical world--couldn't rattle any chains, nor even appear to anybody to scare them. Such ghosts could not even in principle enter in to any scientific account of a phenomenon.

**Edit**
I've received several down votes on this answer, which surprises me, since my answer is clearly correct.

Let me quote some evidence. I'll start with an excellent introduction to the philosophy of mind.

> "If qualia cannot be physically described or explained, then they are not part of the network of physical causal relations that are responsible for human behavior. If qualia are not part of that causal network, however, then they make no causal contribution to human behavior." Jaworski, "Philosophy of Mind: An Introduction" Blackwell 2011, p. 213

Somebody in the comment thread below says that Jaworski, a professional philosopher of mind who published a peer-reviewed book on the subject with a reputable publisher is just wrong about the definition of "qualia."

Ok, so let's look and see what other scholars in standard, peer-reviewed reference works thing.

> "... this response does not apply to those philosophers who take the view that qualia are irreducible, non-physical entities [e.g. Chalmers, Frank Jackson, etc.]. **However, these philosophers have other severe problems of their own. In particular, they face the problem of phenomenal causation. Given the causal closure of the physical, how can qualia make any difference?** For more here, see Tye 1995, Chalmers 1996).'' Michael Tye, in the [SEP article on Qualia.](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/#Uses)

The implied answer of the question is: "They can't." Nobody who believes in qualia should count as a physicalist, but rejecting physicalism is not the same thing as rejecting the causal closure of the physical world. Rejecting closure isn't just rejecting physicalism, it's opening the door back up to straightforward substance dualism where my mental properties cause physical events by pushing my pineal gland around or something.

But, hey, maybe the entire scholarly community has gotten Chalmers and company wrong. Maybe Chalmers has simply been slighted by careless, slapdash slanders by wild eyed physicalists who cannot stand to hear their theories contradicted. So, let's look and see what Chalmers himself says about whether qualia have causal powers.

> "A problem with the view that I have advocated is that if consciousness is merely naturally supervenient upon the physical, then it seems to lack causal efficacy. The physical world is more or less causally closed, in that for any given physical event, it seems that there is a physical explanation of (modulo a small amount of quantum indeterminacy). This implies that there is no room for a nonphysical consciousness to do any independent causal work. It seems to be a mere epiphenomenon, hanging off the engine of physical causation, but making no difference in the physical world." David Chalmers, *The Conscious Mind: In Search of a Fundamental Theory,* Oxford University Press, 1996, p. 150.

Chalmers does go on to suggest ways in which he will try to avoid, or at least soften the blow, of having to make qualia epiphenomenal, but whether those responses are successful is a matter of further scholarly controversy. For my money, I don't think any of his proposed fixes, like endorsing causal overdetermination, or extreme humeanism about causation look even remotely plausible.

I would love for people who are still down voting to explain in the comments exactly what kind of evidence they think would be necessary to prove the claim at issue here. Remember, the issue at stake is not the *empirical* question, "Do psychological states have causal powers?" but rather "Could qualia, those theoretical posits whose properties are stipulated by their use in the philosophy of mind of David Chalmers, Frank Jackson, et al., have causal powers?"

Comment: This answer is incomplete. While qualia are not the proximate causes of any physical events, they are (presuming existence) a characteristic of our interpretation of the world and thus affect how we as agents cause physical events. I.e. there is a feedback loop this answer ignores.

Comment: @JeffY No, they really can't be part of the system in any way. Defenders of qualia grant the sufficiency of physical explanation for all mental phenomena. They think, in other words, that physics can explain the entire story of what's going on with your brain necessary to predict and describe your behavior with 100% accuracy. What they are saying is that there is this separate, non-physical domain which has no causal efficacy whatsoever that is ignored by the physics. But the crucial bit is that these qualia *cannot* explain any physical phenomena, indirectly or otherwise.

Comment: See for instance Jaworski, "Philosophy of Mind: An Introduction" Blackwell 2011, p. 213: "If qualia cannot be physically described or explained, then they are not part of the network of physical causal relations that are responsible for human behavior. If qualia are not part of that causal network, however, then they make no causal contribution to human behavior." This is why qualia fans are called "epiphenomenalists": qualia aren't causes.

Comment: @shane. What you claim to be only a definition is really a synthetic proposition which doesn't seem to fit well with the facts. Jason Holt, for example, said the following: "[I]t is hard to see how we could claim that blindsight is a visual disorder without being able to avail ourselves of the notion that patients lack of qualia. That is the kind of disorder it is." An association such as this which relates qualia with a visual disorder calls into question any supposed definition that makes it out to be merely phantasmagorical. Jaworski is probably mistaken.

Comment: Per @PédeLeão, I also reject the "behaviorism" that is implied by the ideology that "physics can explain the entire story of what's going on". You may have found some "defenders" of qualia that "grant" what you say, but not this one.

Comment: @PédeLeão I've never heard of Jason Holt, but more to the point Jaworski is using the word "qualia" in just the sense that David Chalmers, the person who invented the term, uses it. It's a standard term of art in the philosophy of mind. You're free to use the word to describe something else instead, but you risk simply creating confusion to use the word "qualia" to describe something that has physical causal powers.

Comment: @JeffY You don't have to be a behaviorist to think that physics explains the complete story of what's going on in the brain. Every physicalist thinks that, whether it's reductive physicalism like Lewis and Armstrong or non-reductive physicalists like Ned Block and Jerry Fodor. Epiphenomenalists like Chalmers and and Kim don't want to deny the sufficiency of physical explanation because they don't want to imply the falsity of the principle known as "the closure of the universe under physics". If qualia are non-physical and enter into causal explanations you have to deny closure.

Comment: @shane. But we're not all closure-minded. And in the "Facing Up to the Problem of Consciousness", Chalmers describes qualia as follows: "In this central sense of 'consciousness', an organism is conscious if there is something it is like to be that organism, and a mental state is conscious if there is something it is like to be in that state. Sometimes terms such as 'phenomenal consciousness' and 'qualia' are also used here, but I find it more natural to speak of 'conscious experience' or simply 'experience'." His definition isn't associated with causation as you suggest.

Comment: @PédeLeão If you want to deny closure, that's fine too. At that point you can just be a straightforward substance dualist and think that your immaterial soul is causing physical events (in the pineal gland, or wherever) but the point is just that neither Chalmers nor Kim wants to go that far. (For good reasons, but that's off topic for this question.) At any rate, simply think about Chalmer's zombies to see the point. The thought experiment requires me and a zombie to be exact physical duplicates but I have qualia and he doesn't. That means that qualia must not have causal roles.

Comment: Because everything i do is also something the zombie does, and there *IS* a complete physical explanation of everything the zombie does. That's Chalmers's whole point. You can't explain qualia, so physicalism is false, but you can explain my behavior because qualia have no causal powers, so closure is still true.

Comment: @shane. The point I'm trying to make is that your answer is fallacious, because you claim that it is a definition, but it simply is not. It is making an empirical claim for which you have provided no support, and claiming that everyone thinks the same way is no argument at all. You don't have to argue with me; you can fix your answer and avoid the fallacy.

Comment: @PédeLeão What I have given above *is* a definition. If David Chalmers wants to invent a word to mean a certain entity that is supposed to have certain stipulated properties, he is perfectly within his rights to do so. Whether there are any such objects is, of course, the further, empirical or metaphysical question. But what "qualia" are supposed to be is not an empirical question--they are supposed to have whatever theoretical properties the person who posits them stipulates them to have.

Comment: By the way, Chalmers himself uses p-zombies as an argument **against** physicalism. Don't misrepresent please.

Comment: @JeffY If you'll note, I said above paraphrasing Chalmers: "You can't explain qualia, so physicalism is false, but you can explain my behavior because qualia have no causal powers, so closure is still true." What's the misrepresentation supposed to be? Chalmers denies physicalism and endorses closure. That's absolutely true.

Comment: @shane. That improves your answer a lot (+1), but I still don't think you understood my point. That fallacy was basing your argument on a definition which didn't qualify as a definition. Yes, you quoted philosophers claiming that it's not causal, but none of them claimed that on the basis of definition. If you claim qualia is by definition not causal, then it leaves open the possibility that there exists something qualia-like that is causal. For that reason, its best not to claim your conclusion is true "by definition."

Comment: @PédeLeão I did understand your point. The neutral thing that everybody agrees about is that people have "experiences". I experience seeing red, further, it's clear to everybody that my experiences have causal effects. Chalmers holds that part of my experience is this unobservable, subjective, non-relational feature he calls qualia. Whether there are qualia or not is of course an open question. (my view says no). Could there be other things that have some of the properties Chalmers calls qualia but do have causal powers? Sure. But those things wouldn't be qualia.

Comment: (2/2) Trying to stretch the meaning of the word "qualia" so that it is broad enough to encompass the possibility of them having causal powers is simply inviting confusion. It is a confusion, I add, that I suspect some neuroscientists and AI researchers have fallen into, so I don't blame anybody for falling into it as it is there in the literature. But it is a confusion, nonetheless.

Comment: @shane. I posted my explanation as a an answer and then deleted it after a number of hours. Since you didn't respond, I don't know if you read it or not. Let me know if you want me to undelete it for a little while longer.

Comment: There is wiggle room between Chalmer's epiphenomenal view and  "no way that they could enter into evolutionary or any other kinds of scientific explanation": in principle scientific explanation (description/theory/model whatever) could be constructed that uses qualia in the explanatory framework given the apparently unrecoverable link between  some aspects of human cognition and qualia.  Such an explanation wouldn't be fundamental, but if observable regularities in epiphenomena exist, then there can be scientific work regarding these features.

Comment: For example if you consider "degree of consonance" as being a qualium, then scientific studies like this: http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:66382:5/component/escidoc:468040/Plomp_Levelt_Tonal_1965.pdf provide indications of how to relate physical acoustic characteristics to (reported, averaged) perceptual characteristic of "degree of consonance".  Note that this can be used in the forward sense: if a musician wants to induce a greater or lesser degree of perceived consonance this kind of work indicates how to synthesize tones to achieve that end.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that we all do have subjective experiences which correspond precisely to the information encoded by specific objective brain states, and that the particular subjective qualities which identify different experiences may safely be referred to as qualia, a set of assumptions which some philosophers doubt.

A common tenet of qualia theory is that our objective brain states are driven by the laws of physics, via objective physical processes, and that our subjective or conscious experience of those brain states merely rides on the back of that.

Some, such as Daniel Dennett, hold that such a concept as qualia is therefore worthless; the brain states are all we need concern ourselves with. Others point to the ''sine qua non'' presence of qualia in the mind of every conscious philosopher and may even suggest that this provides unarguable evidence of a metaphysical aspect to the human mind.

Either way, on this basis the evolution of the brain's rational capabilities is driven by broadly Darwinian evolution and consciousness of such reasoning just comes along for the ride.

Modern information theory is beginning to bring another level of sophistication to the argument. For example [Integrated Information Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory) explicitly treats the information flows in the brain as the seat of consciousness, with the physiology and activity of the brain serving only to support sufficiently complex information.

This must surely have profound consequences, for example the laws of physics never lie but semantic information often does, but I have not seen this aspect developed anywhere yet.

Comment: "Some, such as Daniel Dennett, hold that such a concept as qualia is therefore worthless;"  Not sure about the _therefore_, as if it followed from Dennett's being a reductive physicalist.  Because I don't think he is.  I think he is merely pointing out that when you look at a pink thing and are aware of it, it is not because there is something in your brain that is pink, a _figment_ as he calls it.  He's not denying subjective experience, he's saying that the way philosophers try to analyze it leads to problems.  At least that is my interpretation of "Qualia Disqualified".

Comment: Dennett's qualia are not my qualia. "Quale" is just a label adopted to reference something we all experience all the time. The debate is only about the nature of that something. I get the impression that Dennett sets up a straw definition and then burns it.

Comment: " I get the impression that Dennett sets up a straw definition and then burns it."  That could well be the case.  But he's not doing it out of commitment to an extreme form of reductionism.

Answer (score 0):

Qualia are either isomorphic to (if you're a dualist) or identical to (if you're a materialist) computational data structures.

Take the simplest example, the visual field.  The visual field is very similar to a PNG file.  Any computation that could be done with the visual field could be done just as well with a PNG file.

Most qualia are things like sensory experience, emotions, pleasure and pain.  These things are not functional parts of a "general problem solving machine", but rather inputs to a problem solving machine.

Comment: I find your opinion unconvincing. This is from a study on pattern recognition: "This so-called 'invariance problem' is the computational crux of recognition—it is the major stumbling block for computer vision recognition systems (Pinto et al., 2008a; Ullman, 1996), particularly when many possible object labels must be entertained." What evidence do you have that qualia doesn't serve some function for which normal computation is poorly suited?

Comment: @PédeLeão, what evidence is there that qualia does serve a significant function? For all we know the only evidence that it has a function is that people talk about it.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to be "isomorphic to a data structure"? Do you just mean that they have content? Consider a data structure: the variable "OnDesk" and let the value "1" of that variable represent the condition of there being a pen on my desk. Does that make the pen's being on my desk an object isomorphic to a data structure? If so, then I don't see how the concept helps. Everything will turn out to be isomorphic to a data structure. So there's nothing particularly illuminating about saying that qualia are isomorphic to such a structure.

Comment: @daniel, from the point of view of a dualist, why would a problem solving machine need qualia? couldn't it all be done without it? what is information lacking, that a "problem solving machine" would need?

Comment: @nir I'm arguing that, from the point of view of a dualist, problem solving machines don't need qualia.  Qualia are the inputs to the machine, not functional parts.

Comment: @DanielLibicki, it is not clear how qualia causes anything in the world. if so, how can it play the role of input to a computation? such a role is a causal role. not so?

Comment: @nir We don't know yet how qualia cause things.  We can't read the source code of the brain and search for HTTP (or QTP) requests.  But there are good reasons to believe that they do play a causal role.